# Why does Eclipse RCP display warning messages for including certain source files?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Eclipse [bug 286808](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=286808) adds warning messages for including certain files (like `.classpath`, `.project`, `plugin.xml`) in the `src.includes` for a plugin.

Those files seem pretty important for a source release, assuming that you want someone who receives the release to be able to not only code against your plugin but potentially change it. (I guess you could do a source release purely so people can debug against it, but then why would you discourage modification of the plugin by removing these files that are important for development?)

I'm struggling to understand why this change was made. Can anyone provide a reasonable explanation for it?

**Edit:** Example of the warning message: "'plugin.xml' should not be added to src.includes list as it is not required in source build"

**Edit 2:** As can be seen from the answers, I think I asked the wrong question. Should have been: what is the intended purpose of an RCP plugin "Source Build"...

Comment: Q: Can you give an example of one of these warning messages?  Q: Bug 286808 suggests making a "configurable warning".  Did you happen to notice any way to gag the warning in "Eclipse, Properties"?  Q: What version of Eclipse are you using?  Indigo (3.7)?

Comment: @paulsm4 I don't have an RCP install here, but it's something along the lines of "Warning: file-xyz should not be included in the plugin source includes".

Comment: Yes, using Indigo. I'm sure I could turn the warnings off, but I'm trying to work out the thinking behind why they were included in the first place.

Comment: Aren't `.classpath` files unique to a local machine? IE, if Bob wants his libraries in `/usr/lib` and Sue wants her's in `C:/libraries`, that should be allowed and the .classpath will be different for both? Or is this a bad practice?

Comment: @Kane: You can use absolute paths, but I always try to use relative ones to avoid this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my understanding you're not supposed to modify source plug-ins. They are accompanying plug-ins for their binary counterparts to provide the source code (for debugging and generally to make development against these plug-ins easier) and - more importantly - to provide the Javadoc.

If you want others to be able to modify your plug-in you should just offer your zipped project directory.

Jar files in general - to me - are libraries with specific versions that you should take as is. There may be rare reasons why you might have to modify someone else's library for your own purposes but that shouldn't be the norm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I interpret correctly, you're saying that the purpose of a "Source Build" is for reference purposes, and not as something to give someone in order for them to develop with? Do you know of any Eclipse documentation for this?

Comment: Take a look e.g. at the [GEF download page](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/downloads/index.php). `Runtime` is a regular binary build that you need in the deployed application. `SDK` includes the binary build plus the source plug-in. Having the source allows developers that use your plug-in to better debug code and fill in the blanks of the documentation by just looking at the code. With source plug-ins you can just drop them in without having to configure something. So from that point of view the source plug-in is for developers that **use** your plug-in, not for developers that want to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that there is no need to include them:

1. **plugin.xml**: Already integrated in the binary-build.
2. **.classpath**: 
   All classpath preferences can (better: **must**) be read from the MANIFEST.MF. (at runtime you also don't have any .classpath file)
3. **.project**: 
   is always the same (PDE + Java Nature/Builder)

Comment: So, things selected in the Binary Build automatically carry over to the Source Build? Also, the manifest is also one of the files that generates the warning, and doesn't seem to have a lot of overlap with the content of .classpath. And although not mentioned above, ``build.properties`` generates a warning, but without that, you'd have to manually import any resources other than ``src``.

Comment: I get the feeling I misunderstand what a "Source Build" is actually meant to be...

Comment: I think p12t's comment nails it, and you are right, you probably misunderstood the purpose of Source Build.